# Memory Management with NSStatusItem : setToolTip

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsstring, nsstatusitem

I have a Singleton class with static NSStatusItem and a NSStream client. Whenever I receive a message in Stream I pass it to another thread to change NSStatusItem toolTip.

```
  case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: 
    {
        if(stream == inputStream)
        {
            //InputStream ready
            uint8_t buf[1024];
            unsigned int len = 0;
            len = [inputStream read:buf maxLength:1024];
            if(len > 0) 
            {
                NSMutableData* data=[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
                [data appendBytes: (const void *)buf length:len];
                NSString *msgRcvd = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Message Recieved in StreamUtil ::: %@",msgRcvd);
                [self ProcessMessage:msgRcvd];
                [data release];
                [msgRcvd release];
            }
        }
        break;
    }


 @implementation SBNSStatusItem
 static SBNSStatusItem *sbNSStatusItem = NULL;
 +(SBNSStatusItem *) GetSBNSStatusItem
 {
    @synchronized(self)
    {
     if (sbNSStatusItem== NULL)
      {
        sbNSStatusItem= [[self alloc] init];
      }
    }
    return(sbNSStatusItem);
 }

 -(void) CreateNSStatusItem
 {
     // Initalization of NSStatusItem with NSMenu and Image setting
 }

 -(void) SetToolTip:(NSString *) toolTip
 {
   NSLog(@"%@",toolTip);  // Shows Correct Message
   [statusItem setToolTip:toolTip]; // But the ToolTip has some junk at the end of ori msg
   //[toolTip release]; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
 }
 @end
```

Now the Threadfrom StreanUtil calls the setToolTip with the message to be set. But after 2 or 3 calls, the tooltip starts showing some junk text at the end of the original tool tip  message.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Minor points: 1. Don't begin your getter method names using `get`, there's a different convention for Cocoa. 2. Begin your method names with lowercase letters, not with caps.

Answer (score 0):

Since the toolTip item you pass into SetToolTip: is just a pointer its probably getting set or released somewhere else.

try something like this

```
- (void)SetToolTip:(NSString *) toolTip
{
    NSString *toolTipCopy = [toolTip copy];
    [statusItem setToolTip:toolTipCopy];
    [toolTipCopy release];
}
```

Also if your targeting iOS 4 or OS X 10.6 or later I would consider moving to ARC.
Then the code would then become this.

```
- (void)SetToolTip:(NSString *) toolTip
{
    [statusItem setToolTip:[toolTip copy]];
}
```